# onclick event not getting triggered

Tags: android

this is my code, can you tell me whats the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_bf"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="SELECT YOUR LANGUAGES"
                android:textColor="#8E8D8D"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/langDutch"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bg_settings_dutchon_hc_2x"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:onClick="onlanguageSelect"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Dutch"
                android:textColor="#454C52" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/langFlemish"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bg_settings_dutchact_hc_2x"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:onClick="onlanguageSelect"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Flemish"
                android:textColor="#454C52" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/langFrench"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bg_settings_franceon_hc_2x"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:onClick="onlanguageSelect"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="French"
                android:textColor="#454C52" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingscontinue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_hc_bf_language_2x"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="CONTINUE"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is in activity:

```
public void onlanguageSelect(View v){
        Log.v("Language Settings: ", " onlanguageSelect clicked.");
        int id = v.getId();
        String lang;
        switch (id) {
        case R.id.langDutch:
            lang = "nl_NL";
            break;
        case R.id.langFlemish:
            lang = "nl_BE";
            break;
        case R.id.langFrench:
            lang = "fr";
            break;
        default:
            lang = "nl";
            break;
        }
        changeLocale(lang);
    }

    private void changeLocale(String localeString){
        Locale locale = new Locale(localeString);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        Log.v("Language Settings: ", "language changed successfully.");
    }
```

Comment: add this `android:clickable="true"` to your textview and try

Comment: What exectly do you want? A code review or is there really an error.

Comment: @SteveBenett nothing is happening, if it works it should print something on logcat.

Comment: @Raghunandan it worked thanks, but i updated the question, could you help me out.

Comment: @ay89 new query should be posted as a new question. to the original question it was already answered. this will mislead others who visit the post.

Comment: oh sorry, will repost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Raghunandan said, every View have to be marked as clickable to get the onClick handler to work.

Try this for your TextViews:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/langFrench"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bg_settings_franceon_hc_2x"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onlanguageSelect"

            android:clickable="true"

            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="French"
            android:textColor="#454C52" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have implemented the onClickListner() interface in your activity class. 
and also make sure you have register your all TextViews with the interface like this in `onCreate()` method.

```
TextView btnDutch = (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.langDutch);
btnDutch.setOnClickListener(this);
```

this should work.

Comment: there is no button in xml? it's a textview with `android:onClick="onlanguageSelect"` . you are wrong

Comment: still no good ops has this `android:onClick="onlanguageSelect"` on click will go to `onlanguageSelect` method

Comment: I think there is no need to set clickable="true" if you are using the OnclickListner() interface.

Comment: go check the docs. i din't don't vote. but you are wrong. check for `onClick` @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html. edit your answer. or else you will receive more downvotes